# Calc 1 u-substitution, general functions?

Tags: calculus

I was confused by this problem I came across in tutoring today:

Given the integral of f(x) from 1 to 3 equals 4, what is the integral of f(3x) from (1/3) to 1?

If u = 3x, du/3 = dx, so the integral of f(3x) = (1/3) the integral from 1 to 3 of f(u) du.

The naive answer seems to be 4/3, but is this correct?  Something feels wrong about this.  The bounds are in terms of u and the integral is in terms of u.  How can we just say it equals 4 when the original integral was in terms of x?

My gut says there is something wrong about this, can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_1^3f(x)dx=4$ is given and we want to know what $\int_{1/3}^1f(3x)dx$ is.

Firstly let's note that it makes no difference what variable we select:

$$\int_1^3f(x)dx=\int_1^3f(a)da=\int_1^3f(w)dw=4$$

Now to verify your $4/3$ answer you can think up the simplest function that does that job. Why not consider $f(x)=2$ and verify that this integral does what you want it to. That is, imagine the graph and think about what the area under the graph should be between $x=1$ and $x=3$. Then you can imagine $f(3x)$ which just equals $2$ and acknowledge that the area under that curve if you only look from $x=1/3$ to $1$ can only be $4/3$.

For the calculus we should see a $u$-substitution and it may be helpful to see that when we let $u$=blah  that is really a function. That is we let $u$ be some function in $x$ and this is helpful when considering how we have to rewrite the bounds of integration.

$u(x)=3x$ which implies 
$du=3dx$ and we can substitute

$$\int_{1/3}^1f(3x)dx$$
$$= \int_{u(1/3)}^{u(1)}f(u)\frac{du}{3}$$
$$= \frac{1}{3}\int_{u(1/3)}^{u(1)}f(u)du$$
$$= \frac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{3}f(u)du$$
$$= \frac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{3}f(u)du$$
$$= \frac{1}{3}\times4$$
$$= \frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: Why does the choice of variable not matter?

Comment: Because we are running a value from 1 to 3. And it doesn't matter what we call that value.  Say you have a value $x\in[1,3]$ and you consider the area under a curve $f$ as you run $x$ from $1$ to $3$. Say you have a value $w\in[1,3]$ and you consider the area under a curve $f$ as you run $w$ from $1$ to $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=3x$. Then $dx=\frac{du}{3}$. When $x=1$, $u=3$ and when $x=\frac 13$, $u=1$, so $\int_{x=1/3}^{x=1}=\int_{u=1}^{u=3}$. Hence

\begin{align}
\ \int_{x=1/3}^{x=1}f(3x)dx & = \int_{u=1}^{u=3}f(u)\frac{du}{3} \\
\ & = \frac 13\int_{x=1}^{x=3}f(x)dx \\
\ & = \frac 43
\end{align}

The key thing here is that $x$ and $u$ are just dummy variables when you are integrating over them - they have absolutely no meaning since they get integrated out (the final expression is a number which does not depend on $x$ nor $u$).

Hence in the second line above, we can change the variable to $x$.

Comment: I guess I'm still not convinced that the variable choice doesn't matter.  Does this only work for definite integrals?